# Flutter: How to use data stored with SQFlite?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, mobile, sqflite

I'm really struggling with Flutter and SQFlite. There are a load of complex examples around but not a single simple example for just getting data and putting it in a variable for use in a widget or model. I've tried a bunch of examples and most of them give an error "table does not exist". I finally found an example that worked and tried to fork it to work with my needs but I'm just lost. I'm a newbie to flutter but not to coding. Been doing web coding for years. I've wasted hours on trying to just get a simple query to work and returning it's content in a variable. I'm really considering giving up on Flutter completely just because of how hard it is to handle stored data. This should be basic stuff. Why is this made to be so hard!?

Well anyway, here's my code so you can see what I'm trying to achieve. I can create the database, insert and get data inside the DBHelper class, but I have no idea of how to use that data outside it. My goal is to get a simple example to work and then I can implement that in a larger scale to my whole application. I have different kind of dynamic lists etc. Any help will be much appreciated!

database.dart

```
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class DBNoteModel {
  String id;
  String value;

  DBNoteModel({this.id, this.value});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["id"] = id;
    map["value"] = value;
    return map;
  }

  //to be used when converting the row into object
  factory DBNoteModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) =>
      new DBNoteModel(id: data['id'], value: data['value']);
}

class DBHelper {
  Database db;

  DBHelper() {
    initDatabase();
  }

  Future<void> initDatabase() async {
    db = await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), "database.db"),
        onCreate: (db, version) {
      return db.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE notes(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT);
        INSERT INTO notes (id, value) VALUES ('home', 'asd');
        ''');
    }, version: 1);
  }

  Future<void> updateNote(String id, String value) async {
    db.rawUpdate("UPDATE notes SET value = '$value' WHERE id = $id");
  }

  getNote(String id) async {
    List<Map> result = await db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM notes WHERE id = $id");
    if (result.length > 0) {
      return DBNoteModel.fromMap(result[0]);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

test.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../../utilities/database.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DBHelper _dbHelper = DBHelper();
    var note = _dbHelper.getNote('home');
    return Text(note.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have more than one data-record, you need a `List<DBNoteModel>` of your datamodel. In this example it is showing with a Listview

in your `onCreate` command of the database, it is required for each command a seperate `execute` like

```
onCreate: (db, version) async {
  await db.execute("CREATE TABLE notes(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT)");
  await db.execute("INSERT INTO notes (id, value) VALUES ('home', 'asd')");
  await db.execute("INSERT INTO notes (id, value) VALUES ('home2', 'asddf')");
},
```

DBHelper

```
class DBHelper {

  Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDatabase();

    return _db;
  }


  initDatabase() async {
    return await openDatabase(join(await getDatabasesPath(), "database.db"),
      onCreate: (db, version) async {
        await db.execute("CREATE TABLE notes(id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, value TEXT)");
        await db.execute("INSERT INTO notes (id, value) VALUES ('home', 'asd')");
        await db.execute("INSERT INTO notes (id, value) VALUES ('home2', 'asddf')");
      },
      version: 1);

  }

  Future<void> updateNote({DBNoteModel dbnoteupdate}) async {

    _db.update("notes", dbnoteupdate.toMap(), where: 'id = ?', whereArgs: [dbnoteupdate.id]);

  }

  Future<void> insertNote({DBNoteModel dbnoteupdate}) async {

    _db.insert("notes", dbnoteupdate.toMap());

  }

  Future<List<DBNoteModel>> selectNote(String value) async {

    _db = await db;
    List<Map> result;

    if(value == "")
      result = await _db.query("notes");
    else {
      result = await _db.query("notes", where: "value LIKE '" + value + "%'");
    }

    List<DBNoteModel> r_DBNoteModel = result.map((i) => DBNoteModel.fromMap(i)).toList();

    return r_DBNoteModel;

  }

}
```

show some data in a ListView, on tab => update, on textfield change => select Like ?*, on FloatingButton => insert

```
class sqFliteSimpleExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _sqFliteSimpleExampleState createState() => _sqFliteSimpleExampleState();
}

class _sqFliteSimpleExampleState extends State<sqFliteSimpleExample> {

  List<DBNoteModel> dbnotes = new List();

  final DBHelper _dbHelper = DBHelper();

  TextEditingController editingController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    //fetch Notes for the firstTime
    getNotes("");
    super.initState();
  }

  getNotes(String where) {
    // Select with a where or without
    _dbHelper.selectNote(where).then((value) {
      // return value is a List<DBNoteModel>
      setState(() {
        // refresh screen with the new values
        dbnotes = value;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("SqFilte Notes"),),
      body: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Expanded(
            child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: dbnotes.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                return new ListTile(
                  title: Text(dbnotes[index].id.toString()),
                  subtitle: Text(dbnotes[index].value),
                  onTap: () {
                    // updates you local Datamodel
                    dbnotes[index].value = dbnotes[index].value + " update";
                    // send sql Update
                    _dbHelper.updateNote(dbnoteupdate: dbnotes[index]).then((value) {
                      // refresh when it's done
                      getNotes("");
                    });
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: new TextField(
              controller: editingController,
              onChanged: (value) => getNotes(value), // refresh the screen every string input in the TextField
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'search / create',
                border: InputBorder.none,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          //insert a new Note, and refresh when it's done
          _dbHelper.insertNote(dbnoteupdate: new DBNoteModel(id: editingController.text, value: editingController.text)).then((value) {
            getNotes("");
          });
        }
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This clarifies it bit for me. Good and simple examples! Would you know how I could use getNotes with scoped model?